# When to hide() a dijit.Dialog versus .destroyRecursive() in dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, dialog

I have seen both used in code but I was wondering what is the preferred and more efficient method of closing dialogs using dlg.hide() or dlg.destroyRecursive()?

Comment: If you intend to open that dialog again, then hide it.  If you don't (it is a one-off dialog?), then perhaps destroying it will free up some memory.  Not much though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on whether you're going to reuse the dialog or not. If it's cheaper to just re-create it (you define what's cheaper), use `destroyRecursive()`. Otherwise, create once and just `hide()` it any time you need to close it.

Keep in mind dijit will keep all the widgets you create in a registry. So simply letting the dialog variable go out of scope will not make it garbage collectable, and that opens up the possibility of a memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

I find that I cannot completely destroy the widgets inside the dialog if I just call `dialog.destroyRecursive()` though the dialog seems get destroyed.

Instead, I have to call `dialog.hide()` and then call `this.destroyRecursive()` in the `onHide` method.

However, this causes another unharmful error "`exception in animation handler for: onEnd`". 
But it does have all widgets in dialog get destroyed.